# unable to delete a connector when name includes "/"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to delete a kafka connector using rest api through curl and it fails with below
error. connector name includes slash(/).  So far I have used multiple ways to encode slash symbol but result is same.

**Connector Type:** Confluent s3 sink connector 
**Platform:** Confluent platform 5.5 on OCP

**First Attempt:**

```
CONNECTOR_NAME="myconnector/first"
curl -X DELETE "https://localhost/connectors/${CONNECTOR_NAME}"
```

**ERROR:** {"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}

**Second Attempt:**

```
CONNECTOR_NAME="myconnector'\/'first"
curl -X DELETE "https://localhost/connectors/${CONNECTOR_NAME}"
```

**ERROR:** {"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}

**Third Attempt:**

```
CONNECTOR_NAME="myconnector%2Ffirst"
curl -X DELETE "https://localhost/connectors/${CONNECTOR_NAME}"
```

**ERROR:** {"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}

Any help/expert advice is really appreciated.

Comment: So, if you `curl localhost/connectors`, then you have one with a slash? How do you get the config for it?

Comment: using third attempt.  It worked for getting config, pausing connector etc. but doesn't work with delete.